# Can subset of a countable set be uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\sum=\{0,1\}$. I know that $\sum^{*}$ ( the set of all binary strings plus empty string ) is a countable set. Let $B$ be the set of all infinite length binary strings. I know that $B$ is an uncountable set ( in a similar way like set of real numbers is uncountable ). But it seems weird to me. If I am not wrong $B  \subset \sum^{*}$ and yet $\sum^{*}$ is countable and $B$ is not. I am misunderstanding something but can't figure out what.

Comment: Why $B$ is uncountable? Simply becoz it contains all infinite length strings?

Comment: $\sum^{*}$ does not contain infinite strings and hence $B  \subset \sum^{*}$ is wrong.

Comment: $B$ is not a subset of $\Sigma^\ast$, for all strings in $\Sigma^\ast$ are of finite length.

Comment: @cr001 But $\sum^{*}=\{0,1,00,01,10........\}$ the set is infinite so could you explain why it does not contain infinite strings ?

Comment: But, but... $\Sigma^{*}$ contains strings of finite length, *only*; it contains no infinite length sequences. Far from being a subset of $\Sigma^{*}$, your $B$ and $\Sigma^{*}$ are disjoint.

Comment: It's infinite but all it's elements are finite.  This is just like Z every integer is finite.  But the *set* is infinite because there are an infinite number of (finite) integers.

Comment: Yes it contains an infinite number of strings, but it does not contain strings with infinite length. If we list $\sum^{*}=\{0,1,00,01,10........\}$ in the order of length and order of value if the length are the same, then we can apply Cantor's diagonal method to create a string not inside the list.

Comment: @chandresh B must certainly is uncountable. (Cantors diagonal.)  But Sigma star is not and B is *not* a subset of Sigma star.

Comment: @cr001 Not so: you cannot diagonalize out of $\Sigma^{*}$ in the way you describe because the elements are finite strings, the rows are not infinite, for many rows the diagonal will be *empty* as the string will have stopped "to the left of that". You can diagonalize out of the set of all *infinite* strings of 0s and 1s, sure -- that's the usual proof of why that set is not countable.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks a lot. Its clear to me now.

Comment: @BrianO Yes you are correct, I made a mistake when trying to use Cantor's algorithm to create a sample element that's not inside a countable set. I guess I may have to explicitly state something like 1010...where 10 repeats forever, or something like the binary representation of $\pi$ to create such a sample element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"∑∗ ( the set of all binary strings plus empty string )"

This is ambiguous.  Do you mean finite strings only or all strings finite and infinite.

If this includes infinite strings then it is not countable.

If this doesn't include infinite strings than B is not a subset.

===

Ah, Apparently $\sum$ = {0,1} and $\sum *$ is Kleene closure, the set of all *finite* strings of $\sum$.  Kleene closure most certainly is countable.  But B the set of infinite binary strings is *not* a subset of $\sum$*. In fact the two sets are completely disjoint.

(I hadn't come across the notation nor the name "Kleene closure" before. Although the concept of set of finite strings being countable but set of infinite strings being uncountable is very well known under other names and notations.  [Usually I see it referred to as cross-products or sets of n-tuples which is equivalent, of course.])

Answer (score 4):

Briefly, No.

"X is uncountable" *iff* it's not countable *iff* there's no injection $X \to \mathbb{N}$.

If a set $A$ is countable, there *is* an injection $f \colon A \to \mathbb{N}$. If $X \subseteq A$ is any subset of $A$, then $ f \restriction X \colon X \to \mathbb{N}$ is an injection too.

As discussed in the comments to your question, $\Sigma^{*}$ is the Kleene closure of $\Sigma$, thus it's all finite strings of symbols from a typically finite alphabet $\Sigma$. In your example, $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$. So $\Sigma^{*}$ is countable.

Your set $B$ is $\Sigma^{\mathbb{N}}$ ie. $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$,  countably infinite sequences (/ "strings") of symbols in $\Sigma$. Cantor's diagonal proof shows that $B$ is uncountable.

Far from being a subset of $\Sigma^{*}$, $B$ and $\Sigma^{*}$ don't even have one element in common: they're disjoint.